# How Paw read dynamic values from a csv or json file?

Tags: macos, rest, http, paw-app

Can I have Paw for mac (http rest client) read Dynamic Values from a csv or json file? I need to run 10000 APIs by using different Dynamic Values in my collections.

Comment: Not sure if that's still needed in your case, but for the reference, there is no way to do that right now. Though, I take that as a super interesting feature request :) It makes a lot of sense, especially once we add unit testing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a dynamic value extension, and use [readFile()](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Reference/File_Functions) to read your json file.

I have created a dynamic value extension for passwords, and other such stuff that I don't want to share, when I share my Paw documents.

Please note that because of sandboxing, your json file must live inside you extension folder.

Comment: @micha-mazaheri Feature request: Loading config/json files, and being able to reference them as dynamic values.